# How to close dropdown list in combobox On Mouse Move event in VBA?

Tags: vba, combobox

I'm developing a user form in Access. I have this code to open dropdown menu when mouse is on combobox:

```
    Private Sub cmbx_ID_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Me.cmbx_ID.SetFocus
    Me.cmbx_ID.Dropdown
End Sub
```

But I want to close dropdown menu when mouse is away from the combobox (now to close the form he should either select an item in dropdown menu or click on the form). I found that I can create a button and close the form when mouse is on this button:

```
    Private Sub Frame1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    CommandButton1.SetFocus
    SendKeys "{esc}", True    
End Sub
```

but that not what I'd like.